# Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

Tags: centos6, phusion-passenger, dbus

My server on Centos 6.6 went down Phusion Passanger refuses to start of with following error:

```
stdin: is not a tty

/etc/init/delayed_job.conf: line 7: description: command not found
start: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
stop: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Here is contents of delayed_job.conf:

```
description "Start up the delayed_job service"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
    exec 2>&1
    exec su - training -c 'cd /home/training/nyim/current; RAILS_ENV=production exec bundle exec ruby ./script/delayed_job run' >> /home/training/nyim/curr$
end script
```

Folder /var/run/dbus/ is missing system_bus_socket and pid file.

Any clues would be really helpful, i'm puzzled why this happened.

I can start 'service messagebus start' the service, but it doesn't help.

Comment: did u get a solution for this?